# Difference between using Route in App.js and routes.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently doing a personal web-app project with React.js on the frontend side.

I realized that some people try to set `Route path` on App.js when specifying the path. Example:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <div>
                  <Route path="/" exact component={LoginPage} />
                  <Route path="/insta" exact component={APITest} />
                </div>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

However, I also realized `Route path` is used in routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from './App'

export default (
    <Route path="/" component = { App }></Route>
)
```

I am so confused what the differences are and which one we are supposed to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference and you should use it and structure it just the way you like. What you need is to understand how does `Route` actually work, so quoting the main docs:

> Its most basic responsibility is to render some UI when a location matches the route’s path.

So you can think of `Route` as just some kind of wrapper which renders your desired component (via the `component` or `render` prop) when the path in your browser matches your Route `path` prop.

That means you can have multiple `Route`'s with the same `path` - but if you will starting to have a lot of them - it's a good sign to consider a better project structure.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated there is no functional difference. I would highly recommend separating it into a different file as a general rule, this allows you to add routes without your root file becoming too cumbersome it also follows the rule of separation of functions which is good practice in programming.

Comment: Do you mean it's better to put it in `routes.js` instead of `app.js`?